# JSON-RPC - how can one make a unique ID?

Tags: javascript, json, api, json-rpc

When calling a JSON-RPC service what is the most common way to generate a unique ID from a JavaScript client?

#### REVISED QUESTION:

Typically, a JavaScript JSON-RPC client implements a counting `id` parameter (e.g. If the last request was `id=1`, and it hasn't received a response back, the next request is `id=2`. If the request with `id=1` has responded, the next request can be `id=1` again). I'm interested in understanding how people typically implement this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't describe the universe in which this needs to be unique.

If you mean absolutely unique, then you're talking about a [UUID](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/105034/how-to-create-a-guid-uuid-in-javascript).

If you need something unique to the endpoint to prevent client-side caching, then this will suffice

```
var unique = new Date().getTime();
```

If you need something other than these two then you'll need to be more specific.

### EDIT

Maybe something that looks a bit like this

```
jsonRpcClient = function()
{
  var requestStack = [null];

  this.makeRequest = function()
  {
    var id = this.getAvailableSlot();
    requestStack[id] = new this.request( id, arguments );
  }

  this.getAvailableSlot: function ()
  {
    for ( var i = 0; i < requestStack.length: i++ )
    {
      if ( null == this.requestStack[i] )
      {
        return i;
      }
    }
    return i;
  }

  this.request: function( id, args )
  {
    // request stuff here
    // pass id and whatever else to jsonRpcClient.handleResponse()
  }

  this.handleResponse: function( id )
  {
    var request = requestStack[id];
    requestStack[id] = null;

    // Do whatever with request
  }
};
```

Comment: This is just for the client (browser) to match up requests with responses (for async requests). It's not that it has to be as unique as a UUID or even the current time. In fact it could almost always be `1`. It typically starts with `1`, then `2` and so-on, unless `1` is returned before another request is sent (ie, not async). In that case the id is always `1`. I'm more or less interested in finding out how most people are implementing this. I'm sorry for the poorly worded question.

Comment: Sounds like all you need is a "next-available-slot" type of stack, where the array element's index is going to be your ID.